# How to update a table from one database to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two database like A and B and a common table as TBL where the table TBL from A database  has 1555 rows but the table TBL from database has  only 1000 rows. I need to update the TBL in B database from A database. 
1.How can I do it if these A and B database on same server name 
2.what if these both database are on different server names .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server linked servers"

Comment: Formatting your questions adequatly and being more specific makes it more likely that your questions are answered properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO YourDbToBeInsertedInto..YourTable
SELECT * 
FROM  YourDbToBeInsertedFrom..YourTable
WHERE PrimaryKey NOT IN (SELECT PrimaryKey 
                         FROM  YourDbToBeInsertedInto..YourTable)
```

Use linked servers